# Why does a broken mount point break netfilter-persistent using systemd?

Tags: iptables, systemd, samba

I have a relatively clean Debian Jessie install.  I'm running into two related problems:

1) I have a `cifs` mount that shows me an error on boot.  The error says to run `systemctl status home-plex-Media.mount` for details.  The details it gives are:

```
● home-plex-Media.mount - /home/plex/Media
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab)
   Active: active (mounted) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-06-24 04:28:51 CDT; 1min 45s ago
    Where: /home/plex/Media
     What: //192.168.32.1/media
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 309 ExecMount=/bin/mount -n //192.168.32.1/media /home/plex/Media -t cifs -o uid=plex,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,rw (code=exited, status=32)
```

The mount point still works, it's just delayed a bit (I guess).  How can I get rid of the error?

**EDIT:**  I also have a `bind` mount point in `fstab` and it might actually be the culprit for my second issue.  The entry is:

```
/home/plex/Media/plex  /plex  none  bind
```

2) The error in #1 has a weird side effect; it breaks `netfilter-persistent`.  I tested this with a very simple firewall script and the `netfilter-persistent save` command.  The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make sure this is run as root.
if [ $(id -u) -ne 0 ]; then
  sudo $0
  exit $?
fi

_pub_if="eth+"
_localnet="192.168.32.0/24"

iptables=/sbin/iptables

$iptables -P INPUT DROP
$iptables -P FORWARD DROP
$iptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# lo
echo "Allowing lo..."

$iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# _pub_if on _localnet
# this allows all traffic to and from the local network
echo "Allowing local network..."
$iptables -A OUTPUT -o ${_pub_if} -d ${_localnet} -j ACCEPT
$iptables -A INPUT -i ${_pub_if} -s ${_localnet} -j ACCEPT
```

When I comment out the broken `cifs` mount point in `fstab`, my system boots up with `DROP` policies.  When I leave the broken `cifs` mount point in `fstab`, the saved rules are not applied and everything is wide open (`ACCEPT` policies - no rules).

Is there a way to make `netfilter-persistent` fail closed instead of failing open?